# python SQLAlchemy & pandas read_sql_query 日本語の処理について

Tags: python, pandas, 日本語, sqlalchemy

初めまして、こんにちは

sqlaichemyとpandas.read_sql_queryにてmysqlのlike機能で
日本語のキーワードを選択したいですが、どうやって動けますか？

英語のキーワードを下記のように選択すると、動けるんですが

```
statement = "SELECT * FROM orderitem WHERE item_description like '%example%'"
df = pd.read_sql_query(text(statement), engine)
```

日本語のキーワードを使うと、エラーが出てます。

```
statement = "SELECT * FROM orderitem WHERE item_description like '%日本語%'"
df = pd.read_sql_query(text(statement), engine)
```

エラー：

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 55: ordinal not in range(128)
```

ps- このquery "SELECT * FROM orderitem WHERE item_description like '%日本語%'" はterminalで動けるんですが、python で作業するとエラーが出てしまいます。

私のコード：

```
import pymysql
import os
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

db = pymysql.connect(db=db, user='root', passwd=passwd, charset='utf8', unix_socket="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock", local_infile=True)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SET NAMES utf8")
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:passwd@localhost:4406/db?charset=utf8')

statement = "SELECT * FROM orderitem WHERE item_description like '%日本語%'"
df = pd.read_sql_query(text(statement), engine)
```

色々調べたんですenginer とconnetionの方でencoding = utf-8を追加してもうまく解決できません..

よければ教えていただけると嬉しいです。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

結局tell kのコメントに参考し

```
#ダブルクォーテションの前に「u」をつける
statement = u"SELECT * FROM orderitem WHERE item_description like '%日本語%'"
```

で解決しました！

私のpython は2.7で、コードは以下になります。

```
import pymysql
import os
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

db = pymysql.connect(db=db, user='root', passwd=passwd, charset='utf8', 
unix_socket="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock", local_infile=True)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SET NAMES utf8")
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:passwd@localhost:4406/db?charset=utf8')

statement = "SELECT * FROM orderitem WHERE item_description like '%日本語%'"
df = pd.read_sql_query(text(statement), engine)
```

Answer (score 1):

もしかして利用されてるPythonのバージョンは2系ですか？ もしそうなのであれば、SQL文をUnicode文字列で書いてみてください。

```
# ダブルクォーテションの前に「u」をつける
statement = u"SELECT * FROM orderitem WHERE item_description like '%日本語%'"
```

あと `read_sql_query` は 文字列でも多分大丈夫です。(textと、どちらが良いのかはわかっていませんが。)

```
statement = u"SELECT * FROM orderitem WHERE item_description like '%日本語%'"
# text 関数を使わずに直接文字列を渡す
df = pd.read_sql_query(statement, engine)
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。お話通りpythonは2.7です。
教えていただいたコードで試してみると、こんなエラーが出てきました..`unsupported format character '�' (0xffffffe6) at index 54`
やはり難しいでしょうね..

Comment: ありがとうございます。statement でuを使って、pd.read_sql_query(text(statement), engine)でうごきました！！！uを使うのを思いつきませんでした。ありがとうございます！！！